# How to convert a RDD containing a very large number of objects to be a json file?

Tags: json, apache-spark

```
case class VoyageObj(val id:String, val type: String)
```

My question is how to convert a `RDD[VoyageObj]` to be a json file with the format like this:

```
[{
  "id":"111111",
  "type":"Voyage"
},
{
  "id":"111112",
  "type":"Voyage"
}]
```

I know how to do that in terms of a `list[VoyageObj]`. Nevertheless, i have no idea how to do the conversion for a `RDD[VoyageObj]` of more than say 200G.

Comment: It is same as you do for the `list[VoyageObj]`, how have you done for list?

Comment: I did that by gson.toJson(voyageObjList). But I have no clue on how to use it on RDD.

Comment: can't you convert to dataframe and write it as JSON format?

Comment: not yet, mostly because the data in RDD results from a very big hbase table. so i haven't got an effective way to populate the big data to be jsoned. if it's small, it's certainly an easy job

Answer (score 0):

val rdd = sc.parrallelize(List("[" + urJsonRDD.collect() + "]"))

Comment: that doesn't seem to give the format as i mentioned

Comment: the RDD in that question is of very small data, but the one in my question is of tens of millions of lines which couldn't be put in a normal data structure.

Comment: try to convert your object RDD to String RDD like this val JsonData =  youRDD.map( row=> "[{ "+ "id" +":" + row.id+"," +"type : "+ row.type +"}") .
Use a ressource manager if you have one

Comment: it is a string rdd. like this: {
    "id":"aaa",
    "name": "abc"
}
{
    "id":"bbb",
    "name": "bcd"
}
but what i want is like this:[{
    "id":"aaa",
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id":"bbb",
    "name": "bcd"
}]

Comment: val rdd =  sc.parrallelize(List("[" + urJsonRDD.collect() + "]"))

Comment: yes. i have made it by voyageDF.toJSON.collect().mkString("[", "," , "]"). Thank you.